# Remove parentheses from classname using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone tell me how to remove parentheses from a text inside a p class element with Javascript?
I have no access to the html as it is protected by the website provider.

I have the following code:

```
<p class="com-meta">
    <a href="http://nanilümmel.de" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold;" rel="nofollow">Nani</a> <span>(<em>Montag, 03 Februar 2020 17:39</em>)</span>
</p>
```

I want to remove the parentheses from this text here: (Montag, 03 Februar 2020 17:39)

I tried this code here but it's not working:

```
$('.com-meta').each(function(index, item){
    console.log($(item).text());
    var r = $(item).text().replace(/[(\[].*?[)\]] */g, "");
    $(item).html(r);
});
```

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do it this way with replace

First give your anhor tag an id:

```
      <a id="myID" href="http://nanilümmel.de" target="_blank" 
       style="font-weight: bold;" rel="nofollow">Nani</a> 
        <span>(<em>Montag, 03 Februar 2020 17:39</em>). 
         </span>
```

And here the code:

```
      var str = document.getElementById("myID").innerHTML;
      str.replace(")", "");
      str.replace("(", "");
```

Comment: He is using a class --  So assigning an ID is unnecessary --  he is using a jQuery `.each` and the element is assigned to `$(item)`  -- So One *could* just `var str = $(item).html()` within the loop

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the parentheses(brackets) around the date:

```
<p class="com-meta">
    <a href="http://nanilümmel.de" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold;" rel="nofollow">Nani</a> <span><em>Montag, 03 Februar 2020 17:39</em></span>
</p>
```

Comment: The original question was to remove the brackets **using JavaScript**.  This answer is not helpful.

Comment: On the contrary -- If you go back and read the edit history, the original unedited question  reads -->  *Can anyone tell me how to remove brackets from a text inside a p class element with Javascript?   I have no access to the html as it is protected by the website provider.*

Comment: Yup I missed that and deleted my comment.